# Create instance class for a specific constructor

Tags: haskell

Say I have the following data:

```
data A
  = B Int
  | C Float
  | D A
```

If I want to derive `Eq`, but change the output so that comparing two items with constructor `D` will always equal, is there a way to do so without implementing it for all other constructors? For the other cases, I would like to derive the default `Eq` implementation.

What I want to achieve is something along the lines of

```
instance Eq A where
  (D _) == (D _) = True
  _ == _ = undefined -- Use default eq
```

Comment: Kind of. Derive Eq for A, then make a newtype A' = A' A, with a custom Eq.  Then A' is your type. Whether that's with you the hassle depends on the situation

Comment: This wouldn't be a lawful Eq instance. Eq is supposed to mean "nothing in the object's public API can tell these two objects apart". Consider calling this comparison function something other than `(==)`.

Comment: @amalloy do you have a suggestion to handle equality for cyclic types? The reason why I wanted to modify Eq is to avoid unending equality checks.

Comment: I'm sort of curious to know the real world ask that is hidden behind a stack overflow question.

Comment: @MarcTalbot I'm writing a compiler for school. The type data can be recursive (struct with itself as a field), and I want to represent it as such. I also plan on mapping every type to a class name, which is why I want to implement `Eq`. The alternative I can think of is to have no data within the `D` constructor (which represents a cycle), and instead manage the recursive types myself. Neither method really allows for 'lawful' `Eq` instances though, since `D` would depend on the root type, which won't be compared.

Comment: @AllanW the natural derived instance wouldn't give "unending equality checks". It would certainly have *recursive* equality checks, but provided your actual values don't have infinite recursion then the equality checks won't either. After all Haskell lists are a recursive data type, with an unproblematic `Eq` instance - and I don't see your example as being fundamentally different.

Comment: @RobinZigmond an example would be a struct that has itself as a field. In this case, my type would recurse forever, given that one of the fields is defined by the root type.

Comment: @RobinZigmond consider `let {x = 1 : x} in x == tail x`.

Comment: @WillNess fair point, but note I did say "*provided your actual values don't have infinite recursion* then the equality checks won't either" - so this was something I anticipated. But I didn't expect the OP would be working with such values (although it seems now that they are).

Comment: @RobinZigmond I guess I reacted to the other sentence, about the "unproblematic" `Eq` instance for lists, without any qualifications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to incorporate the default `Eq A` instance generated by GHC into your own `Eq A` instance.  The problem is that generation of the code for the instances is tied to the process of defining those instances -- the only way to generate the default `Eq A` code is to actually generate the unique `Eq A` instance, and once the instance is generated, you can't really change it.  I don't see any way, even with GHC "deriving"-related extensions, of working around this problem.

However, there's a reimplementation of the default `Eq` instance provided by the package `generic-deriving` which you could use.  With some preamble:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics
import Generics.Deriving.Eq  -- from package generic-deriving
```

define your data type with a derived `Generic` instance:

```
data A
  = B Int
  | C Float
  | D A
  deriving (Generic)
```

Then, define a `GEq` instance that implements your special case for the `D` constructor while deferring to the default implementation for the rest.

```
instance GEq A where
  D _ `geq` D _ = True
  x   `geq` y   = x `geqdefault` y
```

Finally, define an `Eq` instance the uses this generic equality class.

```
instance Eq A where
  (==) = geq
```

After that, it should all work as expected:

```
> D (B 10) == D (B 20)
True
> B 10 == B 20
False
>
```

However, it might be more reasonable to take the advice in the comments, and either:

1. Do what @malloy suggests. The operation you're trying to define isn't really `(==)`, so why do need to name it `(==)`? Just derive the usual `Eq` instance and write a separate function to avoid the unwanted recursion:

   ```
   equalClasses :: A -> A -> Bool
   equalClasses (D _) (D _) =  True
   equalClasses x y = x == y
   ```
2. If you really want to use a `(==)`, I think using a `newtype` as suggested by @luqui is probably the most idiomatic approach:

   ```
   data A'
     = B Int
     | C Float
     | D A'
     deriving (Eq)

   newtype A = A A'

   instance Eq A where
     A (D _) == A (D _) = True
     A x == A y = x == y
   ```